# How to read .EAP file using java

Tags: java, eclipse, enterprise-architect

Within an Enterprise Architect file I have the definition of an XML (The definition specify which attributes are mandatory or not) , My goal is to read this definition, and afterwards validate the actual XMl file.
 Is there a way to read an .Eap file using JAVA with Eclipse ?

PS: The definition might changes , this why I need to do it programmatically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to an XSD schema?

Comment: No,I have to create one dynamically (depending on the contents of the .EAP file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage a way around it.With the program Entreprise Architect,I exported the model into XML format using the highlighted option below :

[image: export option]

Once the XML is generated,I am able to read the definitions easily with a couple of Xpath queries.

Before that I was  using the viewer version of the program so I didn't have the option to export the model into an XML file. Once I downloaded the trial version , I got this option.
For those who still want to read the actual .EAP, file you can refer to the answer of Thomas Kilian.

Comment: Sometimes the solution is too easy to see :-)

Answer (score 1):

No. Or: not directly. EAP files are actually Mickeysoft Access databases with just another suffix. To read them you need to use the EA API. Or use an ODBC driver for Access.